# NIOServerCnxn@362 - Exception causing close of session 0x0 due to java.io.IOException: Unreasonable length = 1600745078

Tags: java, apache-zookeeper, apache-storm, dropwizard

I am trying to update Apache Storm version to `2.3.0` but after updating dependencies I am getting below error in zookeeper for indefinite time.

```
2022-08-18 06:50:46,431 [myid:] - INFO  [NIOServerCxn.Factory:0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0:2181:NIOServerCnxnFactory@192] - Accepted socket connection from /172.17.0.1:65078
2022-08-18 06:50:46,432 [myid:] - WARN  [NIOServerCxn.Factory:0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0:2181:NIOServerCnxn@362] - **Exception causing close of session 0x0 due to java.io.IOException: Unreasonable length = 1600745078**
2022-08-18 06:50:46,433 [myid:] - INFO  [NIOServerCxn.Factory:0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0:2181:NIOServerCnxn@1008] - Closed socket connection for client /172.17.0.1:65078 (no session established for client)
2022-08-18 06:50:46,540 [myid:] - INFO  [NIOServerCxn.Factory:0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0:2181:NIOServerCnxnFactory@192] - Accepted socket connection from /172.17.0.1:65080
2022-08-18 06:50:46,541 [myid:] - WARN  [NIOServerCxn.Factory:0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0:2181:NIOServerCnxn@362] - Exception causing close of session 0x0 due to java.io.IOException: Unreasonable length = 1600745078
2022-08-18 06:50:46,541 [myid:] - INFO  [NIOServerCxn.Factory:0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0:2181:NIOServerCnxn@1008] - Closed socket connection for client /172.17.0.1:65080 (no session established for client)
```

Apache Storm version update:
`1.0.3` -> `2.3.0`

Comment: How do you run Storm? In LocalMode?